# Creating ON INSERT trigger on Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle10g

I have to create this funky `ON INSERT` trigger on Oracle database.

I have been given this old project that is missing part of the source code so now I have to work some magic using database only. The trigger should update the row on insert with missing values from another view.

Here is some made up sample data:

I have this table, lets call it **TABLE1**.
Then I have this view, lets call it **VIEW2**.
In view there could be more than one record with same CODE but they are exact duplicates, so any row is valid. There is only a few of this duplicates, but the customer has not filtered them out yet.

- **TABLE1** and **VIEW1** have the following fields `(CODE, PARTNER, COUNTRY)`.
- **TABLE1** also has field `COMMENT`.

All fields are varchar type.

In this field `COMMENT` is of `varchar` type and has a suffix added to its value like so:
**"-XXX-CODE"**, for example "some comment-XXX-123".

Here is my scenarion:

This gets inserted in **TABLE1**:

```
**CODE;PARTNER;COUNTRY;COMMENT** 

 - 123;TEST;USA;SOME COMMENT
 - 145;TEST2;GB;SOME COMMENT
 - NULL;NULL;NULL;SOME COMMENT-XXX-154
```

This is where the trigger should kick in.
- IF field **CODE** IS NULL, the trigger shuld fire and
- parse out the code based on the -XXX- prefix (take value 154 in this example)
- make a select on the **VIEW** (select code, partner, country from VIEW1 where code = 154
- if record is found it should update the **TABLE1** with `code, partner and country` value

Well, i hope that the situation is clear.
Since I have no experience with oracle a solution to my problem is much appreciated.

Gratitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is a type of the column CODE so I guessed it is INTEGER.
Here you are

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tri_check_nulls
  BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE1
  FOR EACH ROW WHEN (new.CODE is NULL)
DECLARE
    VIEW_CODE   INTEGER;
BEGIN

    VIEW_CODE := TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(new.COMMENT, INSTR(new.COMMENT, '-', -1, 1) + 1));

    select distinct v.CODE, v.PARTNER, v.COUNTRY
        into  :new.CODE, :new.PARTNER, :new.COUNTRY
        from VIEW1 v
        where v.CODE = VIEW_CODE;

END;
/
```

Of course, you have to add some error handlers.
And please read the Oracle docs [CREATE TRIGGER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm)

Comment: the field code is varchar type. Thanks for the example. Yet i find difficult to understand the SUBSTR/INSTR function in your example based on "-XXX-CODE" sample

Comment: i have tested the functions and now its understandable.

Comment: i am getting compile error: On PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW.COMMENT' must be declared.

Comment: Show me the description of TABLE1, please.